# Why do I get an error using unsquashfs with Clonezilla?

Tags: clonezilla

I am set forth on an adventure to recompile Clonezilla to add a proprietary driver.  In any case, following the instructions here: [unsquashfs ala Clonezilla](http://drbl.sourceforge.net/faq/fine-print.php?path=./2_System/81_add_prog_in_filesystem-squashfs.faq#81_add_prog_in_filesystem-squashfs.faq)

In step 4, `sudo unsquashfs filesystem.squashfs`, fails miserably with:

```
root@debian:~/squashfs-tmp# unsquashfs filesystem.squashfs
Parallel unsquashfs: Using 2 processors
zlib::uncompress failed, unknown error -3
read_block: failed to read block @0x58b68e4
read_fragment_table: failed to read fragment table index
FATAL ERROR aborting: failed to read fragment table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [some googling](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=unsquashfs+read_block%3A+failed+to+read+block) I suspect you have a mismatch between the version of squashfs used to create the filesystem and the version you are trying to use to uncompress it.  What version of squashfs do you have installed?  I recommend you try upgrading to a [newer version](http://squashfs.sourceforge.net/) and see if that helps.

Comment: I will install the same version of debian on my domU, and will build everything based upon what the CloneZilla team used :)

Comment: If you want to see a crazy mind puzzle, i made a video of how my genisofs is breaking, and how much hair i had to pull out, until i made a youtube video for any help possible :)

Comment: http://youtu.be/_oQglMao8FA